# Get tag with no value using jsoup select query

Tags: java, jsoup

Is there any way to get the tags without any value in it using select query (and not jsoup methods ) like:

I tried :matchesOwn("") . As expected it's throwing error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:empty` selector will find elements that have no children at all (including text nodes).

For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3">hello</div>
<div id="4">
    <p id="5"></p>
<div>
```

To select all empty elements, `Elements els = doc.select("*:empty");`

The results will include:

> 0: `<div id="1">`
>
> 1: `<div id="2">`
>
> 2: `<p id="5">`

Note that div 3 and 4 are not selected, because they each have child "values" (be it another element or some text).

You can read more about these selectors [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).